I injured my leg falling off my motorcycle
If I accidentally fell off my motorcycle while riding it, which can I say:

I injured my leg falling off my motorcycle.

I injured my leg by falling off my motorcycle.

I injured my leg from falling off my motorcycle.


Also, how would you expand the ing subordinate clause of (1):
I injured my leg while falling (I fell) off my motorcycle.
OR
I injured my leg because I fell off my motorcycle.

"falling off my motorcycle" is a participial clause; it doesn't have an expansion. Of course you're free to write something longer with because, as a result of, as a direct consequence of etc (but while sounds weird because it sounds like it was a coincidence not cause-and-effect.)

"while" (in the process of) and "because" (as a result of) are not mutually exclusive  ideas and the participial clause expresses both simultaneously.

She injured her back vaulting.  is a normal way of using such a clause, where the participial phrase refers to an activity. falling off a motorcyle isn't an activity.  Such a clause often expresses an effort.  I will do it, or die trying.

Note, the choices that "work" and don't depend largely on this example. #2 might not be the most idiomatic choice here, but it is a valid one, and 3 wouldn't work. But "I got a stomachache from eating too much ice cream" would prefer "from" to "by."

(1) is the most natural. There is really no need to use a preposition; your hearers can imagine that the leg wasn't literally 'injured by' the fact of falling, but by hitting/being dragged along the ground, or being crushed under the bike.

I don't know; I like TimR's assertion that it would be more common to use the -ing phrase for the general activity rather than the accident ("I injured my leg riding my motorcycle"), it would be more common to express the accident with a different structure ("I injured my leg when I fell off my motorcycle" or other options).

Groucho Marx might have quipped: "Interesting occupation you have there, falling off motorcycles. How did you get into that line of work?"
